# Are special characters in Http header "names" valid?

Tags: java, http, web-applications, web, http-headers

I recently used custom headers to override behavior (of our a-b test assignments) of our web application for testing purposes via browser. How it works is that if the application code detects header **names** with certain naming conventions, it processes them, and acts accordingly.

The feature *worked on localhost* and on other in-house environments like qa. But it failed when it went live (our app is a public website running on tomcat and the language is Java 7; qa environment uses the same technologies).

**The root cause** is that the header "naming" convention had special characters in it like dot (.) and exclamation (!). I'm very puzzled that *it works perfectly on internal environments but not on production.* Any ideas how is that the case?

I verified that production code worked if there were no special characters in header names.

Answer (score 4):

The valid characters are defined in http://greenbytes.de/tech/webdav/rfc7230.html#header.fields;  both "!" and "." are valid.

Comment: thanks, I will take a look. But how'd it work on some environments, say localhost?

Comment: Because server implementations differ in their quality?

Comment: A period is allowed in header names. tchar = "!" / "#" / "$" / "%" / "&" / "'" / "*" / "+" / "-" / "." /
        "^" / "_" / "`" / "|" / "~" / DIGIT / ALPHA